# Read a .dat file, split record from each line and save them to individual tables in SQL database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have multiple large dat files which I would like to sort and store in tables in an SQL database.
I want to split them based on the number in position 'x'.

eg. If the number at position 12-13 = '21' add that line to table Record'21'

Eg. Dat file:

```
ABC00000196200014022032205120111    000460019
ABC00000196200014022032205120111    000210019
ABC00000196200014022032205120111    000420019
ABC00000196200014022032205120111    000670019
ABC00000196200014022032205120111    000310019
ABC00000196200014022032205120111    000210019
```

Eg. table record21

```
ABC00000196200014022032205120111    000210019
ABC00000196200014022032205120111    000210019
```

I am coding in VB.NET

I have written the following code to read the dat file, my main issue is how to split it and insert lines into the correct table

```
 Protected Sub ReadDat(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/Files/test2.dat"))
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        Dim Record21 As String = Convert.ToString(lines(i).Substring(12, 2))
       
   
        Insert(Record21)

     Next
End Sub



Public Sub Insert(Record21 As String)
    'Dim str As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(1).ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(GlbSQLCon)
        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO TblRecord21 VALUES(" & Record21 & ")"

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds like you have a design flaw; `21` should be a value in a column in a single table, not part of the name of the table.

Comment: Yikes. This looks scary vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Also, `MsgBox()` and `Server.MapPath()` never belong in the same program.

Comment: You ought to use a `TextFieldParser` to read the data.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'm not sure `MsgBox` belongs in *any* program

Answer (score -1):

I would do this entirely in SQL using a stored procedure to load each file and parse the data into the correct tables but if you are intent on doing it in VB maybe something like this?

```
    Public Sub Insert(Record As String)
    Using con As New SqlConnection(GlbSQLCon)
        Dim query As String = ""
        Dim RecType As String = Record.Substring(11, 2)
        Select Case RecType
            Case 21
                query = "INSERT INTO TblRecord21 VALUES(" & Record & ")"
            Case 22
                query = "INSERT INTO TblRecord22 VALUES(" & Record & ")"
            Case 23
                query = "INSERT INTO TblRecord23 VALUES(" & Record & ")"
        End Select
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I have noted all your comments. The task does not have to be completed in VB. I am unsure how to do this in SQL Server ? Any sample code or article links would be great help as I am always looking to improve thank you